# How to set the picturebox style using SendMessage

Tags: c++, mfc, winapi, visual-c++

I want to set the style of picturebox using `SendMessage()` in win32.

I would like a sample piece of code with enum values for setting style.

Comment: What sort of style do you want to set?

Comment: Like enabling double-buffer,userpaint that sort..
i mean i want to take the current style using sendmessage api and add the doublebuffer,userpaint those sort of style and need to set the updated style using sendmessage.
if u know please help..

Comment: I don't think there is any SendMessage constant that sets the window style.

Comment: @Nick.. ya i tried..i think we need to use setwindowlong API only..
else manually we need to perfom for mobile app's

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the

```
LONG_PTR SetWindowLongPtr(HWND hWnd, int nIndex, LONG_PTR dwNewLong);
```

function which, according to MSDN "function changes an attribute of the specified window.".  The nIndex param should be set to 'GWL_STYLE' and 'dwNewLong' represents the new style.

You can select the various values (use the constants) for the style.

There's a great article exploring this in detail on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997562.aspx which includes a list of the various styles you can set.

Comment: ya.. setwindowLong i know.. but is there any way to apply style with sendmessage API.. particularly with sendmessage

Comment: I can't find a WM_ message which would correspond, but you could use SetWindowLongPtr and intercept the messages and see what actually gets sent to the target's message pump.